# Testing service layer in Spring Boot using Mockito

Tags: spring-boot, testing, junit, mockito, spring-repositories

I am trying to unit test my service layer using mockito having a connection to a Database through the Repository layer.

My test case:

```
@InjectMocks
private EmployeeService employeeService;

@Mock
private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;     

@Test
public void getActionFromEmployeeIdTest() throws ActionException {
 //setup     
 when(employeeRepository.getActionsByEmployeeId(anyLong()).thenReturn(EmployeeEntity);

 // exercise
 List<Employee> result = employeeService.getActionsByEmployeeIdService(101);

 //verify
 assertEqual(EmployeeEntity, result);
}
```

Service Layer:

```
@Service
public class EmployeeService {
    @Override
    public List<EmployeeUser> getActionsByEmployeeIdService(long employeeId)  {
        Employee employee = employeeRepository.findByEmployeeIdId(employeeId);
        List<EmployeeUser> actions = employeeUserRepository.getActionsByEmployeeId(employeeId);
        return actions;
}
```

Repository layer:

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeUserRepository extends JpaRepository<EmployeeUser,Long> {
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "Select e from EmployeeUser e where e.employeeId = :employeeId" )
    List<EmployeeUser> getActionsByEmployeeId(@Param("employeeId") long employeeId);
}
```

I am using `@InjectMocks` for `employeeService` and `@Mock` for `employeeRepository`.

`result` seems to be returning null. Is there anyway I can return a non-null value in my test?

Comment: Why does `getActionssByEmployeeId(anyLong(), anyString())` has two arguments but its declaration has only one?

Comment: @StavShamir, my bad, it was a typo. Test still fails for same reason

Comment: Could you provide your entire test class? The class level annotations may also matter here.

Comment: @StavShamir done

Answer (score 0):

You are using reference of **employeeRepository** to call getActionssByEmployeeId(anyLong()) method.

```
when(employeeRepository.getActionssByEmployeeId(anyLong()).thenReturn(EmployeeEntity);
```

But in service calss this methos is getting called by **employeeUserRepository**

```
List<EmployeeUser> actions = employeeUserRepository.getActionsByEmployeeIdId(employeeId);
```

Please check this.

Comment: employeeRepository and employeeUserRepository are variables which are Mocked and Autowired repectively to the same @Repositroy interface

Comment: Also you are mocking getActionssByEmployeeId not getActionsByEmployeeId or tis this a typo?

Comment: Added test class and fixed typos

Comment: Still there is typo in the method name which you rae mocking. Why don't you put actual test class here.